# Android studio / Gradle strange behaviour

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am experiencing a strange bug with Android Studio with new projects since yesterday (haven't even updated anything):

> - What went wrong:           Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
>
>   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

My build.gradle file doesn't seem to properly recognize Strings:

> buildToolsVersion cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

and puts an error in every line that assigns a String.

Here's my build.gradle (nothing special):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dkslf.fragmenttest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
}
```

What could be wrong here?

**EDIT:** A combination of restarting the PC, restarting Android studio and randomly punching my keyboard seemed to solve the issue for now. 
I'll leave the question open though and see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Have you tried to provide `buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'` double quoted as `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`?

Comment: @Stanislav Yeah, I've tried that. To no avail.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am facing this issue while trying to create a jar from Android studio library project.

Answer (score 1):

Recently ran into this but is not pretty sure if we are on the same boat.
However, this is how I fixed that mockableAndroid problem:

```
-        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
+        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Let's try once.